# How to make a ScrollRect content scroll indefinitely?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a small project o' mine to learn Unity, and I'm stuck at doing an infinite scrolling ScrollRect. I get the idea of spawning/recycling the objects out of the mask, and add correct actions and register, and set the new ones as the last or first sibling of the content panel, according to the movement direction of the content panel, but there is a tiny problem. When I have 100+ objects on that content panel, I can't be expected to make the content panel very long, so that I can scroll it for a very long time. What I need, is to scroll a small (still bigger than mask) panel for an infinite amount. How can I do it?

I'm currently playing with normalizedPosition, and to scroll back to top of the panel (or bottom, according to whichever direction I'm headed at), this is how my OnDrag method looks like;

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    if (transform.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition < 0.15f)
    {
        transform.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.88f;
    }
    if (transform.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition > 0.90f)
    {
        transform.GetComponent<ScrollRect>().verticalNormalizedPosition = 0.17f;
    }
}
```

My class is implementing IDragHandler, by the way, if any info about that is required.

Comment: What if you're scrolling really fast and go from a vertical position of 0.89 to 0.99? You shouldn't snap it hard to 0.17, you should add or subtract a value.

Comment: I don't scroll, but rather let only drag work on it. I've implemented IScrollHandler to "devour" that action in nothing. While dragging, I didn't understand what you meant by "adding", but I'll try to add 0.02 to vertical normalized position when it's 0.99, and hope that it'll scroll back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing some examples I've found over internet, I've decided to make the content panel movement type "Unrestricted", thus, making the panel scroll as I want. I'm placing the buttons, children of the content, by hand. There are small mathematical problems here and there, and when resizing on the height, new buttons form up somehow odd, but still, I've achieved infinite scrolling effect.

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    _yMargin = ScrollContent.transform.position.y - _dragStart;
    Debug.Log(_yMargin);
    //todo: howmanybuttons shows how many lines should be filled. Take sign to determine way, take number to determine line no.
    int howManyLevels = Mathf.Abs((int)(_yMargin / _buttonHeight) / 2);
    Debug.Log(howManyLevels);
    if (Mathf.Sign(_yMargin).Equals(1))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < howManyLevels; i++)
        {
            _dragStart += _buttonHeight;
            _upCount += 2;
            PanObjectPoolManager.Recycle(ScrollContent.transform.GetChild(0));
            PanObjectPoolManager.Recycle(ScrollContent.transform.GetChild(0));
            _button = PanObjectPoolManager.Spawn(ButtonObject, ScrollContent.transform);
            _button.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = _downCount + "";
            BuildOnCoords(_downlevel, true);
            if (_downCount == 99)
                _downCount = -1;
            _downCount++;
            _button = PanObjectPoolManager.Spawn(ButtonObject, ScrollContent.transform);
            _button.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = _downCount + "";
            BuildOnCoords(_downlevel, false);
            if (_downCount > 99)
                _downCount = 0;
            _downCount++;
            _downlevel++;
            _uplevel++;
        }
    }
    if (Mathf.Sign(_yMargin).Equals(-1))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < howManyLevels; i++)
        {
            _dragStart -= _buttonHeight;
            _downCount -= 2;
            PanObjectPoolManager.Recycle(ScrollContent.transform.GetChild(_childCount - 2));
            PanObjectPoolManager.Recycle(ScrollContent.transform.GetChild(_childCount - 2));
                _button = PanObjectPoolManager.Spawn(ButtonObject, ScrollContent.transform);
            _button.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = _upCount + "";
            _button.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
            BuildOnCoords(_uplevel, false);
            if (_upCount < 0)
                _upCount = 99;
            _upCount--;
            _button = PanObjectPoolManager.Spawn(ButtonObject, ScrollContent.transform);
            _button.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = _upCount + "";
            _button.transform.SetSiblingIndex(0);
            BuildOnCoords(_uplevel, true);
            if (_upCount == 0)
                _upCount = 100;
            _upCount--;
            _uplevel--;
            _downlevel--;
        }
    }
}
```